# Filter a String value in a list

Tags: c#, string, list, lambda

I have the following list:

```
List<String> randomWords = new List<String>();
randomWords.add("Hello");
randomWords.add(" ");
randomWords.add("how");
randomWords.add("are");
randomWords.add(" ");
randomWords.add("you?");
```

I want to display :

```
> Hellohowareyou?
```

I could do something like

```
foreach(String word in randomWords)
{
     if(word!=" ")
     {
         Console.WriteLine(word);
     }
}
```

But i want to be able to use a lambda expression like :

```
foreach(String word in randomWords.where(p=>p.value!=" "))
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Am i forced to make a specific class which will contain a String i can filter or is there a way with Strings ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var message = string.Join("", randomWords.Where(val => val != " ").ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .net 4, [string.Join has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an `IEnumerable<string>` in parameter:

```
string concated = string.Join("", randomWords);
```

And if you want to add a predicate:

```
Func<string, bool> predicate = word => (word != " ");
string concated = string.Join("", randomWords.Where(predicate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ForEach`:

```
randomWords.ForEach(word => { if (word != " ") Console.Write(word); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> randomWords = new List<String>();
randomWords.Add("Hello");
randomWords.Add(" ");
randomWords.Add("how");
randomWords.Add("are");
randomWords.Add(" ");
randomWords.Add("you?");

Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(randomWords.Where(w => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers explain the use of string.Join that I, too, highly recommend.
For the actual condition, you should use string-functions:

```
string concated = string.Join("", randomWords.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n)));
```

EDIT: Actually when not in need of a delimiter string.Concat is a better solution (not adding a delimiter is potentially faster than adding an empty one):

```
string concated = string.Concat(randomWords.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n)));
```

Comment: Why should i use a string.Join ? Is it the fastest processing ?

Comment: You're right. I meant that I prefer the given string-methods over something like ForEach or else.

Answer (score -1):

A quick way:

```
var s =string.Join("",randomWords.Select(x => x != " "));
Console.Write(s);
```